# invisible view toolbar action

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I wanted to make invisible some action added to the view toolbar based on perspective change.
Following is my code for making a particular action invisible. This code does not give me any effect.
The code executes fine, but it does not disappear from the toolbar.

```
IContributionItem[] items = view.getToolbar().getItems();
                    for (IContributionItem item : items) {
                        if (item instanceof ActionContributionItem) {
                            ActionContributionItem actionItem = (ActionContributionItem) item;
                            if(actionItem.getAction().getId().equals("actionid")){
                                //view.getToolbar().remove("actionid");
                                actionItem.setVisible(false);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `update()` method on the toolbar manager.

See this snippet where an item gets invisible after 5 seconds:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final ToolBarManager toolBarManager = new ToolBarManager();
    final Action action1 = new Action("1") {
    };
    action1.setId("1");
    toolBarManager.add(action1);
    final Action action2 = new Action("2") {
    };
    action2.setId("2");
    toolBarManager.add(action2);

    toolBarManager.createControl(shell);

    display.timerExec(5000, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final IContributionItem[] items = toolBarManager.getItems();
            for (IContributionItem item : items) {
                if (item.getId().equals("1")){
                    item.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
            toolBarManager.update(true);
        }
    });

    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```